# Обособление оборота с "как", обозначающего признак подлежащего

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложениях такого образца: "И наконец надумал, захватил планшет и, как был в халате, так и отправился к другу"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*И наконец надумал, захватил планшет и **как** был в халате, **так и** отправился к другу.*

В этом предложении не нужно ставить запятую перед ***как***. Здесь имеет место парный союз ***как... так и...***

[**КАК... ТАК И**, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_352)

> Запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза (перед словом «так»).
>
> *Глянул дядя Зуй и **как** стоял, **так и** сел в снег.* Ю. Коваль, Стожок. *Эта конференция собрала представителей **как** федерального, **так и** регионального уровня.*

Подробнее о парных союзах написано в справочнике Розенталя, в параграфе  [**Однородные члены предложения, соединенные двойными или парными союзами**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=161).